# thmtools: command to print theorem name

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I'm using amsthm and thmtools for my theorem environments. Is there any way to print the name of a theorem? For example, given the following code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[name=My Title]
    \label{myonlytheorem}
    My theorem text.
  \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Is there a command, say `\thmname{myonlytheorem}`, that prints the theorem's name, i.e., "My Title"?

Comment: you're using `amsthm`.  `amsthm` provides a `\newtheorem*` command that allows you to define a theorem with a unique name; it's described on page 2 of the manual (`texdoc amsthm`).

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I want it to be a "normal" theorem without a unique name. Most of the times, it shall be referenced like "Theorem 1". There is only one exception, where I want some kind of reminder like "Theorem 1 (My Title)" to be printed additionally.

Comment: it seems that you want this as a reference.  that's not crystal clear in your question.  no, that isn't provided by `amsthm`.  you might just define a command yourself, since there's only one of these, say `\newcommand{\mytheoremname}{my title}` and use that in both the theorem heading option and as the reference in the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package `nameref` to cross-reference the name of theorem `myonlytheorem` by writing `\nameref{myonlytheorem}`

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[name=My Title]
    \label{myonlytheorem}
    My theorem text.
  \end{theorem}

  My theorem is called \nameref{myonlytheorem}
\end{document}
```